# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then under what other conditions on $\sigma(p^k)/2$ does $k=1$ follow?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $N = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes (1638), Frenicle (1657), and subsequently [[Sorli (2003) - Conjecture 3, Chapter 5 on page 89]](https://opus.lib.uts.edu.au/bitstream/10453/20034/2021/02Whole.pdf) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds for an odd perfect number $N = p^k m^2$.

It is fairly easy to [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262319) that if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is prime, then $k = 1$.

Moreover, [Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou (2013)](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) show that if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is a square, then $k = 1$.

An interesting scenario holds when $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree.  Indeed, this assumption implies that
$$H = \gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)) = \frac{m^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2} = G \times J^2$$
is **not squarefree**, where $G$ and $J$ are defined as
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(m^2)) = \dfrac{\bigg(\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m)\bigg)^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2}$$
and
$$J = \dfrac{m}{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m)}.$$
(For the case under consideration, that $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree, we do in fact have
$$G = \sigma(p^k)/2$$
and
$$J = \dfrac{m}{\sigma(p^k)/2}$$
since $\sigma(p^k)/2 \mid m^2$, and therefore $\sigma(p^k)/2 \mid m$, holds in general.)

Here is my initial question:

**FIRST INQUIRY**

> Can you show that $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree likewise implies that $k=1$?

The reason for this inquiry is because I currently [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335854) that $k=1$ likewise implies that $H$ is **not squarefree**.

**LAST INQUIRY**

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then under what other conditions on $\sigma(p^k)/2$ does $k=1$ follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial response, as it does not directly answer the original question that was asked.  Additionally, what follows are actually some remarks that would be too long to fit in the *Comments* section.

---

This answer builds on the results in [this MSE question from January 03, 2023](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609954), and shows that
$$H = \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}$$
is **not a square**, if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree.

---

Throughout [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116), we implicitly rely on the simple equality
$$\sigma(m^2) = \frac{2p^k m^2}{\sigma(p^k)}. \tag{1}$$
Unfortunately, this seems to introduce fractions.  To avoid that, we can use prime factorizations, as follows.  Write the prime factorization of $m$ as
$$m = {q_1}^{a_1} \cdots {q_n}^{a_n},$$
for some unique odd primes $3 \leq q_1 < \ldots < q_n$, and for some positive integer exponents $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.  Since both sides of $(1)$ are integers, and since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ with $p$ prime, we know that
$$\sigma(p^k) = 2 {q_1}^{b_1} \cdots {q_n}^{b_n}$$
for some nonnegative integers $0 \leq b_i \leq 2a_i$.  Thus, we have
$$\sigma(m^2) = p^k {q_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {q_n}^{2a_n - b_n}.$$

Suppose that $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree.  This assumption implies that
$$\sigma(p^k) = 2 {q_1}^{b_1} \cdots {q_n}^{b_n}$$
for $0 \leq b_i \leq 1$.

Since
$$\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} \geq \frac{p^k + 1}{2} \geq 3,$$
then $b_i = 1$ for at least one $i$.

This means that
$$H = \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = {q_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {q_n}^{2a_n - b_n}$$
where $2a_i - b_i = 2a_i - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for at least one $i$.

Consequently, $H$ is **not a square**, if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree.

Comment: In fact, by the **contrapositive**, if
$$H = \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \frac{m^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2}$$
**is a square**, then $\sigma(p^k)/2$ **is also a square** (and therefore, is **not squarefree**).